# How to create a Coda plug-in which creates a new site?

Tags: cocoa, plugins, shell, coda

I'm using Coda for web developement. I often create new sites in my `~/Sites` folder. I always enter the same information in Coda, except for the name of the site, and the directory where it's stored. Is it possible to create a plug-in (in either Cocoa or ShellScript) which automates this (so I don't need to enter all FTP stuff etc... over and over again)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do it: just make a generic site with the things you normally type in. Then 
when you want to create a new site, right-click on the generic site and say **duplicate**. There's no shell script you can write for the process, because you would need access to Coda's inner workings.

@Joshua I think Koning is talking about the process of creating a 'Site' within Coda itself, which looks like this:
http://andrewcerniglia.com/blogImages/77437/Coda_addSiteFTP.jpg

Comment: That's probably the best method. Having written several Cocoa plug-ins for Coda I know there is no way to do this with the current Cocoa plug-in API. It might be possible with Applescript.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [plugin](http://www.nuguerrilla.com/) for that. It should do what you're looking for. If it doesn't, a similarly-worded Google search turns up this [Coda plugin development page](http://www.panic.com/coda/developer/howto/plugins.php).